# How do I make create a (more than one) popup text box that appears on mouse-over AND if user clicks on "+" sign

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

What is the simplest/standard way to create a popup text box that appears in an HTML page both if the user does a mouseover and also stays visible if the user clicks on the "+" sign and off again if the user clicks the "-" sign.

I need:

1. To be able to have more than one visually separate popup boxes (containing different text) on the same HTML page.
2. It is important that the user does not set scrolled or moved anywhere on the page during a mouse-over or click-to-expand.
3. I also want it to be possible that in some of the popups I can code them to already be open when the user first loads the page.
4. I am working on a large old website and I also need to be able to over-write the CSS styling that is already in place for  links.
5. I need it to toggle between something like "More (+)" and "More (-)" depending on whether or not the popup box was open. (Perhaps this would be better done using graphics rather than text I just don't know...!)

I am using HTML, CSS and Javascript (although I dont know if I really need Javascript nor what the issues are between using and not using Javascript)

So far this is what I have:

HTML:

```
  <p>
  This is my main text about say, Rugby. Blah blah... 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleView('contentFees', this)" ><span class="revealLink">More (+)</span></a>
  </p>

  <div id="contentRugby" class="revealInfo" style="display:none;">
 Rugby is a dangerous game played by loonatics etc etc... </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .revealInfo { 
     background-color:#f4f4f4;
     padding:10px 25px 15px 25px; 
     Margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  }
  .revealLink{ 
  font-weight:bold; 
  color:#CCC; 
  }
  .revealInfo:hover{display:"";}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleView(id, link) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == '') {
      e.style.display = 'none';
      link.innerHTML = 'More (+)';
    } else {
      e.style.display = '';
      link.innerHTML = 'More (-)';
    }
  }
  </script>
```

It sort-of works with the "More ()" text being able to toggle between "(+)" and "(-)", however I cant get the mouse-over to work at tall.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

J

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you download the latest bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com and check out the popover instructions. Don't invent the wheel yourself but checkout what's already available.

Comment: I am not currently allowed to add a whole new CSS to the site. And with bootstrap it looks like we'd need to (either that or I guess paste the Bootstrap CSS onto the end of our [already too large CSS). As a last resort I might have to but I am trying to keep things simple.

Comment: Ok but you can use only the javascript solution to use for you modal screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onmouseover and onmouseout javascript events.
Have you tried this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="toggleView('contentFees', this)" onmouseout="toggleView('contentFees', this)" onclick="toggleView('contentFees', this)" >
```

Use this

```
<p>
        This is my main text about say, Rugby. Blah blah... <a href="javascript:void(0);"
            onclick="toggleView('contentRugby', this, 'click')" onmouseover="showView('contentRugby', this, 'click')"
            onmouseout="hideView('contentRugby', this)"><span class="revealLink">More (+)</span></a>
    </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var openedByClick = false;
        function toggleView(id, link, src) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if (e.style.display == 'none') {
                showView(id, link);
            } else if ((src != 'click' && openedByClick == false) || src == 'click') {
                hideView(id, link);
            }
        }
        function hideView(id, link) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            e.style.display = 'none';
            link.innerHTML = 'More (+)';
        }
        function showView(id, link, src) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            e.style.display = 'block';
            link.innerHTML = 'More (-)';
            if (src == 'click') {
                openedByClick = true;
            }
            else {
                openedByClick = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The problem is that as soon as the user clicks, the very first thing it does is make the text disappear!

And then yes, when you mouse off it turns out that it has fixed the text to appear.

To recap, what I need it do is:
1. Text needs to appear when the user does a mouse-over (this works)
2. When the user clicks it 
a) CONTINUES to stay visible, but 
b) it fixes the texts so that when the user does a mouse-off the text stays visib

The mousing over and the clicking must not interfer with each other.

Comment: P.S. Drat my nice layout in my comment above just got crushed!